# Web APi Fast download for huge files in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, iis, asp.net-web-api

Good evening,

I am trying to improve the performance in getting files from a web api in a c# .net application. The c# application is using high CPU usage plus it dosnt seem to be very quick a 1GB file locally is taking around 40 secs. The machine is running high speed NVMe SSD so i dont believe its down to hardware.

Note the below is being tested on the same machine. We are experiencing slow speed in prod but that could be due to network or other issue. Therefore i just want to check if there are efficiencies to made in the code base.

The WPF application code for downloading is:

```
  public async Task Test()
    {
        AppModel.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        var sourceFile = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("e820e6d8-4544-4f17-84e3-61e90ccd7e24.zip");
        var url = $"api/UploadDownload";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppModel.BaseUrl);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AppModel.Token);

            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            using (var streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                var fileToWriteTo = Path.GetTempFileName();
                using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(fileToWriteTo, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo);
                }

                AppModel.EndTime = DateTime.Now;
                var difference = AppModel.EndTime - AppModel.StartTime;
                var totalSeconds = (int) Math.Round( difference.TotalSeconds);
                AppModel.TotalSeconds = totalSeconds;

                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileToWriteTo);
                AppModel.TotalMbDownload = ConvertBytesToMegabytes(fileInfo.Length);
                var averageSpeed = AppModel.TotalMbDownload / totalSeconds;
                AppModel.Speed = averageSpeed;

                File.Delete(fileToWriteTo);
            }
        }
    }
```

The api code is as follows:

```
   [HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetSingleFile()
    {
        var dh = new DirectoryHelper();
        var sourceDir = "";

        // var filepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadDownloadLocation"] + "\\" + fileName;


        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        var filepath = sourceDir + fileName;
        var localFilePath = filepath;

        if (!File.Exists(localFilePath))
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
        }
        else
        {
            // Serve the file to the client
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = "test.zip"
                };
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful, not sure if there are better ways to increase performance.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything obvious with the code. It's more likely a constraint of the network (switches, adapters, bandwidth), and we're not in a position to assist with that.

Comment: Your question doesn't state where you think the bottleneck is. Do you think it's slow on the server or slow on the client? Have you performed profiling or other testing and tried using other clients and servers to try to spot any difference?

Comment: Its on the same machine, its a development box

Comment: Your dev box is then transferring data between the disk and CPU for both operations in opposite directions. There are a number of potential hardware bottlenecks at play, and it's not surprising.